# How to get text from website in Qt (QNetworkAccessManager not working)?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I am trying to get text from a website using the `QNetworkAccessManager` class, but it's not working. [When the replyFinished slot above is called, the parameter it takes is the QNetworkReply object containing the downloaded data as well as meta-data (headers, etc.)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#details). When the slot gets called, I append the gotten text to a QString and print it out, but it prints an empty string. Here is my code:

```
//.pro file
TEMPLATE = app
QT += qml quick
QT += network
CONFIG += c++11


//xmlparser.h
#ifndef XMLPARSER_H
#define XMLPARSER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>

class XMLParser : public QNetworkAccessManager
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ~XMLParser()=default;
    static XMLParser &Instance();
    Q_INVOKABLE void readXML();

signals:
    finished(QNetworkReply* reply);

public slots:
    void replyFinished(QNetworkReply* reply);

private:
    XMLParser()=default;
    XMLParser(XMLParser const&)=delete;
    void operator = (XMLParser const&)=delete;

    QByteArray m_text;
};

#endif // XMLPARSER_H


//xmlparser.cpp
#include <QUrl>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QEventLoop>
#include "xmlparser.h"

XMLParser &XMLParser::Instance()
{
    static XMLParser instance;
    return instance;
}
void XMLParser::readXML()
{
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
            this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
    manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://qt-project.org")));
}
void XMLParser::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    QString text;
    text.append(reply->readAll());
    qDebug () << "Text: " << text; //Prints out emtpy string?
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"?

Comment: Note that the url you specify `http://qt-project.org` is actually a redirect (or actually a series of them).  Try setting the [`QNetworkRequest::FollowRedirectsAttribute`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkrequest.html#Attribute-enum) attribute.

Comment: I changed the link to 'http://www.textfiles.com/etext/FICTION/80day10.txt' but it still doesn't work.

Comment: `class XMLParser : public QNetworkAccessManager` - why??? This is useles. Also you can add error checking at `replyFinished` slot.

Comment: I realized it does work with plain text files. However, I need to process an XML file so I think I am going to download the file and then process it.